# How to express this Linq query with OfType(string typeName)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

How to express this Linq query with OfType(string typeName)?:

```cs
context.Products
    .OfType<BlazorStore7.Data.Entities.Cat_Hat>()
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.IsEnglishAttrNames)
    .Select(d => EF.Property<string>(d, prop))
    .First()

context.Products
    .OfType(tptName)
    .OrderBy("what should be this")
    .Select("and this")
    .First());
```

EDIT:

```
public class Product
{
}

public class Cat_Shirt : Product 
{
   string properties
}

public class Cat_Hat : Product 
{
   string properties
}
```

IsEnglishAttrNames is known string value and I have tptName and each prop as string variables.

Comment: just convert above query with its equivalent (bellow) so that it is passed a string (tptName) instead of strongly typed type name, And I don't understand minus points since this is a good question.

Comment: You cannot call `OfType(some string)`. Of what type is `context.Products`? Is there a inheritance hierarchy that you want to filter?

Comment: This doesn't look like the right approach. What problem are you really trying to solve here? If your table(s) contain types of different types then there likely is a discriminator column which you could use to dynamically filter with `Where()` instead of `OfType()`.

Comment: If you don't know the type at compile time, how do you propose to make the `OrderBy` functions etc? It makes no sense.

Comment: @mz1378, Where is your classes hierarchy? Should we follow all your questions on SO? Why one property is dynamic?

Comment: This is a TPT hierarchy and this kind of syntax is available in ef core, so I just want to use this since I have entity type name as tptName and I have each property name as string prop.

Comment: `string properties` in each class are not related to each other. You should move it into a single property in the base class

Comment: If you must use child-type-specific properties you must use a switch-statement anyway and so you can use `OfType<TypeName>()`.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I changed the second query to:

```
context.Products.OfType(tptName).OrderBy("IsEnglishAttrNames descending").Select(prop).First();
```

and it is working.

Comment: This isn't a useful answer. We don't know what `tptName` is in your `OfType` method, and LINQ's `OrderBy` doesn't even take a string parameter that would explain the `"IsEnglishAttrNames descending"` argument.

Comment: Strange question and strange self-answer. Update at least with information that you are using Dynamic LINQ, which is third party library.

Comment: There is no way this is working, it's not valid code using the normal EF libraries.

Comment: This works good and I have written some methods based on this and tested them all working, As I said above in the original question I have string variables of tptName ("Cat_Shirt" or "Cat_Hat") and have all properties of Cat_Hat or Cat_Shirt as a string List using this linq query: var columnNames = context.Model.FindEntityType(
    Type.GetType(TitleTPT)).GetProperties().Select(x => x.GetColumnName()).ToList();